# concat pdf tables into one excel table using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf, tabula-py

I'm using `tabula` in order to `concat` all `tables` in the following [pdf file](https://www.docdroid.net/s3iN7Pp/goal-pdf)

To be a one table within `excel` format.

Here's my code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd

allin = []
for page in range(1, 115):
    table = read_pdf("goal.pdf", pages=page,
                     pandas_options={'header': None})[0]
    allin.append(table)


new = pd.concat(allin)

new.to_excel("out.xlsx", index=False)
```

Also i tried the following as well:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd

table = read_pdf("goal.pdf", pages='all', pandas_options={'header': None})

new = pd.concat(table, ignore_index=True)

new.to_excel("out.xlsx", index=False)
```

Current output: [check](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/officeapi/v1/73e5843f8f93328ec4f60eb32a6bd45dbf22e761f155147495009debb7a1ea56fcfae262af30ebea1c48fe732c61bbac5f6bc772285ba3459c7db5b555b49090)

But the issue which am facing that from page# `91` i start to see the data not formatted correctly within the `excel` file.

I've debug the page individually and i couldn't figure out why it's formatted wrongly especially it's within same format.

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd

table = read_pdf("goal.pdf", pages='91', pandas_options={'header': None})[0]


print(table)
```

[image]

**Example**:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd

table = read_pdf("goal.pdf", pages='90-91', pandas_options={'header': None})

new = pd.concat(table, ignore_index=True)

new.to_excel("out.xlsx", index=False)
```

Here I've ran the code for two pages 90 and 91.

starting from row# 48 you will see the difference [here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/officeapi/v1/387152d9a59702853e89a46e422fc4f66f22b3ec1dc130f7ff371f059c07374eba159dd77305a06b709c69f98b0acc80475a50ca799a1551b2be8d3522507007)

Where you will notice the issue that name and address placed into one cell. And city and state placed into one call as well

Comment: what means "data not formatted correctly" ? Show what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Have you checked the output which I mentioned within my post, if you just ran the code against page# 90 then 91 so you will get it

Comment: I checked page in link `check` but I don't see anything special and I don't know what to search because  I don't know what means `"data not formatted correctly"`. And I'm too lazy to run code to see output.

Comment: @furas alright, I've edited my question now. hopefully it's better now to get it. as i were trying to avoid long question :)

Comment: do you means that in some rows you have `["DENTON",  "TX"]` and in others `["DENTON TX", ""]` ? You could describe it in question because it is not so easy to see. You could join both columns and again split on last space.

Comment: The issue within city and state yes and also within name and address. As you might noticed they are placed into one cell

Comment: it is easy to correct city and state - connect both and split on last space - but big problem makes name and address because names are different and it very hard to recognize end of name. It would need rather work with PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged in source code and it has option [columns](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/tabula/io.py#L777) and you can manually define column boundaries. When you set `columns` then you have to use `guess=False`.

`tabula-py` uses program [tabula-java](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java) and in its documentation I found that it needs values in percents or points (not pixels). So I used program [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to measure boundaries in points.

[image]

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd

# display all columns in dataframe
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

columns = [210, 350, 420, 450]  # boundaries in points
#columns = ['210,350,420,450']   # boundaries in points

pages =  '90-92'
#pages = [90,91,92]
#pages = list(range(90,93))
#pages = 'all'  # read all pages 

tables = read_pdf("goal.pdf",
                  pages=pages,
                  pandas_options={'header': None},
                  columns=columns,
                  guess=False)

df = pd.concat(tables).reset_index(drop=True)
#df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace=True)  # convert first row to headers
#df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)           # remove first row with headers 

# display

#for x in range(0, len(df), 20):
#    print(df.iloc[x:x+20])
#    print('----------')

print(df.iloc[45:50])

#df.to_csv('output-pdf.csv')

#print(df[ df['State'].str.contains(' ') ])
#print(df[ df.iloc[:,3].str.contains(' ') ])
```

Result:

```
                                      0                         1       2   3               4
45                        JARRARD, GARY      930 FORT WORTH DRIVE  DENTON  TX  (940) 565-6548
46                        JARRARD, GARY        2219 COLORADO BLVD  DENTON  TX  (940) 380-1661
47  MASON HARRISON, RATLIFF ENTERPRISES  1815 W. UNIVERSITY DRIVE  DENTON  TX  (940) 387-5431
48  MASON HARRISON, RATLIFF ENTERPRISES          109 N. LOOP #288  DENTON  TX  (940) 484-2904
49  MASON HARRISON, RATLIFF ENTERPRISES      930 FORT WORTH DRIVE  DENTON  TX  (940) 565-6548
```

---

**EDIT:**

It may need also option `area` (also in points) to skip headers. Or you will have to remove first row on first page.

I didn't check all rows but it may need some changes in column boundaries.

---

**EDIT:**

Few rows make problem - probably because text in `City` is too long.

```
col3 = df.iloc[:,3]

print(df[ col3.str.contains(' ') ])
```

Result:

```
                              0                       1                 2         3                 4
1941  UMSTATTD RESTAURANTS, LLC  120 WEST US HIGHWAY 54  EL DORADO SPRING      MS O    (417) 876-5755
2079               SIMONS, GARY         1412 BURLINGTON  NORTH KANSAS CIT      MY O    (816) 421-5941
2763       GRISHAM, ROBERT (RB)   403 WEST COURT STREET    WASHINGTON COU  ORTH HOU  S(E740) 335-7830
2764            STAUFFER, JACOB   403 WEST COURT STREET    WASHINGTON COU  ORTH HOU  S(E740) 335-7830
```